# How should be a SPDX license name when extracting from another file content?

Tags: spdx

Following the [SPDX simple license expressions](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/SPDX-license-expressions/#d3-simple-license-expressions) and the [License identifier field example](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/other-licensing-information-detected/#1013-examples), when creating a custom license that's not listed in [licenses list](https://spdx.org/licenses/) (including exception), I could use `LicenseRef-ACME`, where `ACME` is my company name, or even, my project name in a repository.

However, when having to extract a license text from a header, to distribute that custom license as a separated file, I'm not sure about:

- The license name that should be used (e.g. `LicenseRef-ProjectName`)
- The license file name that should be used (e.g. `LICENSE`)
- Custom fields in the license file to refer where I extract that text.

I read about [DocumentRef](https://spdx.github.io/spdx-spec/v2.3/file-information/), but I'm not sure if it's the case, and how to use it.